# Как устроена доменная система ?

Tags: домен

Объясните мне, как происходит регистрация доменов?
Кому сообщает сервер, что ресурс находящийся по адресу example.com будет лежать у него(ip)
в в таком-то месте (host)?

Comment: лучше возьми и почитай специальный статьи по этому вопросу, потому что в 2х словах все просто, есть компьютер, который хранит пары, айпи - доменное-имя, к нему приходит запрос, он перенаправляет его на нужный сервер... =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сама система называется DNS.

Например можно почитать [Wiki](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS)

UPD: Т.С - ваш вопрос не корректно сформулирован... Регистрация и собственно domain2ip это разные операции...

Answer (score -2):

Гораздо понятнее будет прочитать небольшую главу в этой книге: "[Компьютерные сети](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/7309924/)" там все очень подробно с картинками и примерами.

Comment: Извините, а за что "-" ?

Comment: Имхо - Предлагать купить книгу за 1к, ради пяти копеечного вопроса...

Да и free ( благо dns - открытая информация ) источников - более чем много....

Comment: за "типа неявно, ни разу не паливную" скрытую рекламу
****
PS:ставил не я, претензии не ко мне xD
****
Я же написал - претензии не ко мне =)

Comment: Если Вы посмотрите историю правок, то увидите, что я давал ссылку на сайт, где ее можно скачать,  а за меня пост отредактировали.

Comment: "PS:ставил не я, претензии не ко мне xD
Я же написал - претензии не ко мне =)"
Это "обработанный" комментарий или я что-то туго понимаю?

Comment: Нда..., если в ответе было одна ссылка, а @ХэшКод ее заменил на другую, то это **очень некрасиво**.

Comment: Я: за "типа неявно, ни разу не паливную" скрытую рекламу
@DUP: Если Вы посмотрите историю правок, то увидите, что я давал ссылку на сайт, где ее можно скачать, а за меня пост отредактировали.
Я: Я же написал - претензии не ко мне =)

Причем тут @ХэшКод?

Comment: Все, теперь понял. Смутила фраза , что претензии не к Вам написанная два раза подряд.

Comment: To @AlexWindHope 

    "Причем тут @ХэшКод?"

притом, что ответ от @DUP в 17.37 правлен @ХэшКод в 17.51, а @DUP утверждает, что ответ за него отредактировали.